# Trying to use classes in Tkinter to create multiple frames

Tags: python, class, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to create 2 frames in my main parent widget - one using the `grid()` method and the other the `pack()` method. I wrote it first in a procedural way and it was way too messy, so I'm trying to use classes to clean up the code. Below is the relevant code, where I try to create 2 frames using the **init** method but it throws me all sorts of errors.

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    """This class creates packed frames for the GUI"""
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.framepack = Frame(master)
        self.framepack.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        self.framegrid = Frame(master)
        self.framegrid.pack(side=TOP)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        #Container 1 using LabelFrame, houses email and password labels and entries
        self.inputlabels1 = LabelFrame(self, self.framepack, text="Input email login information here")
        self.inputlabels1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.emailfield = Label(self.inputlabels1, text="Email Address")     #Labels
        self.passfield = Label(self.inputlabels1, text="Password")

root = Tk()
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The entire thing just falls apart. The problem code is this:

```
        self.inputlabels1 = LabelFrame(self, self.framepack, text="Input email login information here")
```

I'm trying to put this Labelframe widget into one of the two frames I initialized earlier, framepack but it throws me errors. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I amended your example, so that it works, and displays something. At the current form, it does not work. Also, I added colors to frames, so that they are easily seen. This helps in organizing your layout, and understanding what is happening:

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    """This class creates packed frames for the GUI"""
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        # added width=180, height=40, background='red'
        self.framepack = Frame(master, width=180, height=40, background='red')
        self.framepack.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

        # added width=180, height=40, background='green'
        self.framegrid = Frame(master, width=180, height=40, background='green')
        self.framegrid.pack(side=TOP)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        # Container 1 using LabelFrame, houses email and password labels and entries

        # Removed `self,` from the orginal code.
        self.inputlabels1 = LabelFrame(self.framepack, text="Input email login information here")
        self.inputlabels1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)        
        self.emailfield = Label(self.inputlabels1, text="Email Address")     #Labels

        # Called pack()
        self.emailfield.pack()
        self.passfield  = Label(self.inputlabels1, text="Password")

        # Called pack()
        self.passfield.pack()

root = Tk()
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer would be better if you also described what you did. Otherwise readers have to scan the code line-by-line to see what you did.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks. I added comments clarifying what was changed.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to give your `LabelFrame` two parents. The parent should be `self.framepack`. Removing the first argument should fix the problem:

```
self.inputlabels1 = LabelFrame(self.framepack, text="Input email login information here")
```